# Android repeat insert values SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

the user enters values ​​in the db .... now I wish that he can choose to repeat the automatic insertion over time, that is, every 10 days, every 30 days etc ...
How can I do this?
I can use SharedPreferences or something?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AlarmManager](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/) to that time. Once the alarm is raised. Insert your data. Moreover when the alarm is raised check preference to set the next alarm.

Comment: you have an example for me? to store the data using this code

`cv.put(GTable.EN, mImporto.getText().toString());
   cv.put(GTable.NO, mNote.getText().toString());
   cv.put(GTable.CAT, spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());`